# How would the rest of the world look if the sea level rose high enough to submerge the British Isles?

Tags: geography, science-fiction, geology

I'm doing some planning for a fantasy comic and I was just wondering how the rest of the world would look if sea levels rose enough to completely submerge the U.K. Specifically I'm interested in mainland Europe and Eastern Europe as that's where I'll be setting my story. 
 Any picture representations would be greatly appreciated if anyone has the time! Cheers!

Comment: Welllll... sea level can only go up about 70m (all ice melted), and UK goes up to 1000m, with most of Wales, Northern England and Scotland being well over 70m.  Do you still want us to answer pretending it went up 1000+m?

Comment: [A Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=highest+point+in+the+uk) shows the highest point to be Ben Nevis in Scotland. It stands at 1344m, which would put it way out of reach of a complete icecap melt. You'd have to have a bunch of ice fall from the sky to reach that level. Maybe you want submerge all of the *inhabited* places in the UK? I'm thinking that would be a lot less improbable? Just a thought.

Comment: Thermal expansion of water might get you beyond the level increase just from molten icecaps. A hotter Earth beyond that which melts all the icecaps might get you there. Highly saline water would have a higher boiling point than 100°C, and might be required before a sufficiently hot Earth to expand the water enough would begin to boil away the water.

Comment: Ah, I guess I'll have to settle with just just the lower lying inhabited parts of the U.K being submerged seeing as how physics wants to crap on my fire! Cheers for the input all!

Comment: Actual science: often takes the fun out of sci-fi.

Comment: The Earth would be a smoking, desolate crater. If it was even intact enough to be called a planet, after you slammed an 800-km wide ice comet into it to provide the water needed.

Answer (score 13):

It would look like that by adding 600 meters above the water level.

source: http://www.floodmap.net/?ll=50.338547,13.093127&z=4&e=600

Image [image]

Comment: Vincent.  That's awesome!  You rock!